# Can PhpStorm keep maximum blank lines or not allowed empty line after '{'?

Tags: php, phpstorm

I notice that PhpStorm has a setting : "Keep Maximum Blank Lines Before '}' "
But is there a possible way of not allow empty line after `{` braces ?

Usually `{` appear after function, class or JSON data, empty line should not appear in all above scene.

I found a setting can control it : "Keep Maximum Blank Lines In Code", if set to 0, then after `{` will not have empty line, but sometimes coder need add some empty line to make code clear.

Although this is not a big thing, but always make me uncomfortable.

Any help?

[image: the setting of before '{']

[image: empty line after braces]

Comment: **1)** *"I notice that PhpStorm has a setting"* Your IDE version? It's there for PHP -- you must be using old version.Please upgrade to latest stable.  **2)** *"Usually { appear after function, class or JSON data,"* Formatter rules are per language; Such option may be available for one language but not for another (for whatever reason).

Comment: My PhpStorm version is 10.0.3, and I just don't want a empty line after '{' in PHP.

Comment: The option is there in 2017.2.4. Your IDE version is soon to be 2 years old (there were 5 major releases since then; 6th one is expected in less than a month) -- lots of new stuff was added.

Comment: Thank you so much, I see the feature in Phpstorm 2017.2.4. I love Phpstorm much more.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47256357/is-phpstorm-possible-auto-complete-db-field-as-a-string-in-php-file  a question that confuse me long time.