# Is PhpStorm possible auto complete DB field as a string in PHP file?

Tags: php, phpstorm

PhpStorm is fantastic to me, I love it so much. 
During my using, I image that if PhpStorm can auto complete DB field? If can, that will be awesome!

Such as DB table name is `table_a`, in there is a field `aaa` in that table. After I connect DB in PhpStorm, if type `a` character, there will not pop up `aaa`. Only after typed `aaa` already in php file, then next time PhpStorm will pop a correct tips that I real want.

I know PhpStorm can be used as DB query string editor, if type complete long SQL string. e.g. `select aaa from table_a`, during the typing, PhpStorm is smart in complete tips.

But most time, coder will use develop frame such as Yii, then a complete SQL string is not require, only DB field need in string. such as: `->select('aaa')` but I need type it all by hand.

Is it possible in PhpStorm? Connect DB in PhpStorm, and type part field character then pop up the complete existed DB field in string or as a variable name.

Comment: No. Because 1) context is not clear -- even if SQL command is expected here, but what kind of SQL command? 2) completion works in proper SQL strings where you clearly have the command that will be executed (e.g. `SELECT ... FROM ...` or `INSERT INTO ...`) as IDE verifies whole command not just part of it. For example -- for your `->select('aaa')` -- what table that would be? what DB (quite often you may have more than 1 DB defined) etc.

Comment: Thanks, may be the context is no need. Just treat db table name/field name as a normal string wait to complete. PhpStorm could tips every variable name and string that occur before when you type the short key alt + / , so db complete could do the same. May be Phpstorm should add this feature in the future.

Comment: You can open Database tool window, find that table and just copy fields from there (one by one or few at once; in latter case they will be each on separate lines). Check -- it works just fine -- it will insert just a field name and nothing more. Some links: 1) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Databases+and+SQL+Editor+in+PhpStorm 2) https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2017/06/20/working-with-sql-and-databases-in-intellij-based-ides-webinar-follow-up/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to have the autocomplete in a string. As [mentionned in the doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/running-injected-sql-statements.html), put your cursor in the string, press `alt + enter`, select `Inject language or reference >`, in the search box, type the sql you are using and selection it.

You can also inject the language using PHPDoc, eg.: `/** @lang SQL*/`, but the tables auto complete might not work.

Do not forget to properly set and test your database connection in the Data source and Drivers before.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
$query = /** @lang MySQL */
<<<SQL
SELECT ... FROM table
SQL;
```

see also:

`Settings -> Languages & frameworks -> SQL Dialects`

`Settings -> Languages & frameworks -> SQL Resolution Scopes`

this is useful if U have some datasources and want to tell PHPStorm which is used in project / file